# Postgres regexp replace using another table for both the regexp and replacement values

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table with key/values where the key is a regular expression and the corresponding value is the replacement value. For example:

```
table_a:

Key   Value
-----------
a     123
b     456
c     789
```

I need to update a value in another table using SQL by replacing every key that appears in the table above with it's corresponding value.

If I had a single replacement value, I would use something like this:

```
UPDATE table_b 
SET    some_field = REGEXP_REPLACE((SELECT STRING_AGG(table_a.key, '|') 
                                    FROM   table_a), 'replacement value');
```

This would construct a single regular expression based on all the `keys` in table_a and replace any occurrence with my replacement string.

How could I do something similar but use the corresponding `value` from table_a as the replacement value?

Using Postgres 9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that in a single execution of `regexp_replace()`. You need a loop and multiple calls of `regexp_replace()` for all rows of the `table_a`. So, you need a plpgsql function:

```
create or replace function replace_all_patterns(str text)
returns text language plpgsql as $$
declare
    r record;
begin
    for r in
        select key, value
        from table_a
    loop
        str:= regexp_replace(str, r.key, r.value, 'g');
    end loop;
    return str;
end $$;
```

Assuming that the `table_b` contains two rows:

```
create table table_b(some_field text);
insert into table_b values
('abc'),
('ccc');
```

you can use the function in this way:

```
update table_b
set some_field = replace_all_patterns(some_field)
returning *;

 some_field 
------------
 123456789
 789789789
(2 rows)
```

It is worth adding that the function is rather expensive and that the results in some cases may depend on the order of rows in the `table_a`.